# How to find element based on Material-icons name?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the html that i need to find via JavaScript:

```
 <i class="material-icons bh-icon-accordion">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

I've got one `arrow_up` element and several `arrow_down` elements, so finding the element by `class` is not an option. Also, the item doesn't have an `id` attribute so `document.getElementById` is not an option.

Is there a way to find it by "`keyboard_arrow_up`" ?

Comment: You can find the element based on the text inside, but it's against the best practices as it would be a really heavy and low performance action. What you should do is to give the element a class name when it's arrow up so you can select it by the class.

Answer (score 2):

As @AminJafari said in the comment, it is a very heavy operation to do and it could kill your performance. You can still limit your elements in first instance and filter them later, this will have a lower impact:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.material-icons'))
  .map(_ => _.innerText)
  .filter(text => text === 'keyboard_arrow_up');
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't hurt to give it an #id that you can select it by..

```
<i class="material-icons bh-icon-accordion" id="my-selector">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

Or even add an additional class

```
<i class="material-icons bh-icon-accordion my-selector">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

So that you can use a querySelector on your element

```
const el = document.querySelector("#my-selector");
```

or

```
const el = document.querySelector(".my-selector");
```

In Angular, use the @ViewChild decorator with a template reference.

```
<i class="material-icons bh-icon-accordion" #myselector>keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

Then in your class, bind to it with ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('myselector') 
private myElement : ElementRef;
```

Don't forget to import ViewChild from @angular/core